# Can't use Barcode scanner in Cordova (plugin is installed).

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I'm having a problem with my `Cordova` app when trying to use a barcode scanner plugin.

The plugin seems to be installed correctly, since when I type in `cordova plugin ls` 
I get the response:

```
    [ 'com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner',
  'org.apache.cordova.console' ]
```

However I tried multiple ways of triggering the scanner but none worked. I also copied the barcodescanner.js into my `www folder` and in my `index.html` even if I read it's not necessary anymore.
The suggested way in the read-me file is:

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan()
```

which didn't work out. I tried numerous other things but none of them worked.
Now I'm hoping someone here encountered the same issue and found a solution.
I'm testing the iOS app version.

Comment: what is the error generated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your config.xml

```
<feature name="BarcodeScanner">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner" />
</feature>
```

and while using the plugin

```
function clickScan() {
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
  function (result) {
      alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
  }, 
  function (error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
  });}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me out. However did/do you use this scanner yourself? Because I didn't get it to scan any Barcode I tried (Bottles / Cards / Books / etc.)